# Android radio streaming - on activity resume - plays again

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I'm building a Android app that streams simple radio station.

**EDIT:** I added the OnCreate event and the init() function.

on create:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        play_or_pause();

    }
```

the init() function:

```
    public void init() {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            stream_url = "http://the_radio_station.m3u8";
            playing_now = false;
            fb_error = "";
        }
```

on created I'm calling the AsyncTask method:

```
play_or_pause();
```

the AsyncTask method:

```
public class play_or_pause_AsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<Boolean, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Boolean... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (!params[0]) {
                fb_error = "";
                try {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isLooping() || mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    fb_error = String.valueOf(mediaPlayer.isPlaying());
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stream_url);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    playing_now = true;
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    fb_error += e.toString();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    fb_error += e.toString();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    fb_error += e.getMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    fb_error += e.toString();
                }
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                playing_now = false;
            }
            return fb_error;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
//           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fb_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

when I'm opening another Activity and coming back to the MainActivity(which making the stream) its starting to run the streaming again without stooping the old one.

I reed many posts here, the only suggestion was to use:

```
if ( mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.stop();
```

but it ain't helping (someone wrote that the mediaPlayer object is strange, you cant tell what is the objecct real status - Like if the .isPlaying() is true / false).

so what I can do in this situation?

Comment: If you're trying to stream/play something independent of the activity state, you ought to use a foreground service (with notification). If you want to stop/pause the stream when your activity loses focus, then you need to stop it in `onPause()`. Unfortunately, you didn't include your activity lifecycle methods here.

Comment: I added the OnCreate Event and the init() function

Answer (score 0):

try this way i use everytime

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```